# How can I update the markers when moving the map?

Tags: android, google-maps, algolia

I am using Algolia's InstantSearch Android library.

This is my Query:

```
searcher.setQuery(new Query().setAroundLatLngViaIP(true).setAroundRadius(5000)).
```

But when I move the map, the markers stay in place. How can I display the new markers on the map when I move the map location view?

Comment: Hi Thofiq, welcome to Stack Overflow! Remember to accept/upvote the answers that solve your problem, to reward the person who takes time to help you and to let other people know this was helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to listen to the map changes and every time the user is dragging the map and reload the results? Here's what you should do:

```
public class AwesomeCameraActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnCameraIdleListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_camera);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;

        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);

        // Show the initial position
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(YOUR_LATITUDE, YOUR_LONGITUDE), 10));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        // The camera / map stopped moving, now you can fetch the center of the map
        GeoPoint center = mMap.getProjection().fromPixels(mMap.getHeight() / 2, mMap.getWidth() / 2);
        double centerLat = (double)center.getLatitudeE6() / (double)1E6;
        double centerLng = (double)center.getLongitudeE6() / (double)1E6;

        // Now fire a new search with the new latitude and longitude
        searcher.setQuery(new Query().setAroundLatLng(new AbstractQuery.LatLng(centerLat, centerLng)).setAroundRadius(5000))
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad. Change the variable `geoPoint` to `center`. And import `import com.google.maps.GeoPoint;` I made the changes in the code, should work now

Comment: Thanks but the marker is continuousblinking. And i added Toast message (for lat lng value) also continuously displaying. I thing it is looping then how to stop it

Comment: You should save the `GeoPoint center` as an instance variable and compute the new center every time. And then compare if the new center is far enough from the one saved. If is far enough, re-do the search. Otherwise don't do anything

Comment: GeoPoint is not working still, but except of that i am solved the issue by this  
LatLng target = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;

Is this right way ?

Comment: Indeed, you can try that. Did you add the `import com.google.maps.GeoPoint;` at the beginning of your class?